# How can I change Windows user name through the filesystem?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, reset

I changed my Windows' user name and now I can't log in. Windows shows me the previous user name at start up and denies any passwords.
Hopefully, I have access to my Windows directory through Linux dual boot.
**Can I change the user name back or reset the password through the filesystem?**

Comment: No( use the built-in Administrator account

Answer (score 0):

- If it's a local account, and the disk is not encrypted, it is easy to remove the password [with a rescue disk](https://www.appgeeker.com/password/remove-a-windows-7-password.html).
- If it's a Microsoft account, MS *might* be able to help.
- If the disk is encrypted, recovery may not be feasible.

As Ramhound states, use the Administrator account to recover what you can, and create a new user.

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't used encryption for user data, then `ntpasswd` is for you. It will reset password for user. But if you encrypted user data - it will be lost (you will be not able to decrypt it).

Comment: Please explain why minus.